# How do I get "xmi:type" value

Tags: acceleo

I am trying to generate a java program to implement a State Machine from a UML model using Acceleo.

In my model I have entries like:--

```
 <subvertex xmi:type="uml:State" xmi:id="{BB1999-E740-4e7d-A1BE-F099BEXYD970}" name="WaitingApproval">
```

I want to check the value of "xmi:type" but I cannot work out how to access this from Acceleo. (I have tried every combination of gets I can think of and the type only appears as part of a longer string if I dump the whole vertex.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024563/how-to-get-xmiid-from-xmi-files-in-acceleo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the `subvertex` relation, you must be on a `Region`. The `xmi:type` is the way XMI handles polymorphic references. As `subvertex` is defined as `Vertex [*]`, XMI must specify the type of each element in the collection. To check this field, you simply need to test the type of the element (using `oclIsTypeOf` or `oclIsKindOf`)

So, from a `Region`:

```
[template public test(r : Region)]
[r.subvertex->filter(State)/] --> filter all States from the subvertex collection
which is equ. to
[r.subvertex->select(oclIsKindOf(State))/]
and if you want only the State elements (no subclasses)
[r.subvertex->select(oclIsTypeOf(State))/] 
[/template]
```

Also, you can handle them in different templates by adding template guard:

```
[template public test(r : Region)]
[r.subvertex.test2()/]
[/template]

[template public test2(s : Vertex) ? (oclIsKindOf(State))]
[s/] is a state for sure
[/template]
```

you can also avoid guard by rewriting the above templates as this:

```
[template public test(r : Region)]
[r.subvertex.test2()/]
[/template]

[template public test2(v : Vertex)/]
[template public test2(s : State)]
[s/] is a state for sure
[/template]
```

**EDIT**

If you absolutely want the type value in a String format, you have to go check the element metaclass and ask for its name:

```
...
[s.eClass().name/] -> result as String, s.eClass() gets the EClass
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Could not see oclIsTypeOf in the available methods!